DAX ignoring subset of slicer filters in measure
I am working on PowerBI desktop.
I have a table "DataTable", with lots of columns, including such columns as "date", "is_user_valid", "country", "value" etc.
In the report, there is a slicer which shows different measures per country, on which many filters to "DataTable" applied to make measures results more specific.In general, there are >30 filters, including filters on "date=01-Jan-2024", "is_user_valid=yes", "country" and others.
I need to create a new measure for this slicer, which will be showing SUM(value) for the specified date (01-Feb-2024) for "is_user_valid=no". It means, that all other slicer filters should be kept for the measure, while those two should be replaced by the values specified directly (Date=01-Feb-2024 and is_user_valid=no).
I found one way to solve the task, but it is too inconvenient:
NewMeasure = Calculate(
sum(value),
ALLEXCEPT('DataTable', 'DataTable'[Country]),
'DataTable'[date] = "01-Feb-2024"
'DataTable'[is_user_valid] = "no"
)


This method is not good because, as I said, slicer has 30+ filters, and here I have to specify all of filtered fields in "ALLEXCEPT" function to keep them.
I've tried to solve the problem using ALL (it works, but all filters lost), "REMOVEFILTERS" (applying that just gives me Blank), and ALLSELECTED (also, blank).
Do not know what to try else.
Example with REMOVEFILTERS:

NewMeasure = Calculate(
sum(value),
REMOVEFILTERS('DataTable'[date], 'DataTable'[is_user_valid]),
'DataTable'[date] = "01-Feb-2024",
'DataTable'[is_user_valid] = "no"
)



What does your version with REMOVEFILTERS look like?

Hi @SamNseir! Please look on the updated description, I've added  version with REMOVEFILTERS

See if this works, using ALL on the Columns only.
NewMeasure = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM(value),
    ALL('DataTable'[date]),
    ALL('DataTable'[is_user_valid]),
    'DataTable'[date] = "01-Feb-2024",
    'DataTable'[is_user_valid] = "no"
  )

Failing that, see if you can share a simple PBIX (share URL via OneDrive, Google Drive, DropBox etc...) replicating the issue (doesn't have to have the 30 slicers, just a couple).

Of course =) It is not working, as in the context of the slicer, there is already a filter on date (date=01-Jan-2024), while here we specify an additional filter on date (date=01-Feb-2024), which contradicts each other. Same for the second filter

Updated answer above with ALL(table[Column]). Also your REMOVEFILTERS option should of worked, so something else is at play here, like maybe there just isn't any results for those two with all the other filters applied.

Yep, that was the first thing I tried. By some reason it is also not working. When I use "ALL('DataTable')", it clears all filters and it works, but no slicer filters remain.
But when I do "ALL('DataTable'[date])" it just ignores it, it seems. Date is still shown as "01-Jan-2024" when I replace SUM(Value) by MAX(date)

Sorry to ask, but is your date column a proper date column or text? If date then you need to update it to DATE(2024, 2, 1), and is your date slicer based on the same column or a related table?

That is a date type, I just used simplifications here to not write all those parts with DATE(...). In my code, I use a variable for the date calculated based on the "date" column. But the problem comes not from here, as this date is calculated properly.

I've checked the data also, and there are no contradictions there, so one should be able to calculate SUM(value) with those filters together. I've also checked it using "ALLEXCEPT" with all columns specified there, and it worked as expected

Regarding slicer - it actually has two filters applied - on related table and on this column itself
